# Action doesn't work anymore with an image buttom?

Tags: android, image

I have a simple app with 2 buttoms, which trigger a notification. Later in the progress of programming i wanted to change the normal buttoms to image buttoms because of the better design, so i deleted the normal buttoms and but image buttoms in and **changed the id back to the original** buttom1 and buttom2, **but now it doesn't work anymore**. What have i done wrong? Do i have to programm image buttoms diffrent to the normal ones? Do i have to install libarys or somthing? Please helb me!

xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/buttom2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttom1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttom1"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/buttom1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon1" />
```

main.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }


    public void sendNotification(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()){

            case R.id.buttom1:
                Notification1();
                break;

            case R.id.buttom2:
                Notification2();
                break;


            }
         }

   private void Notification1() {

       NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
       builder.setAutoCancel(true);
       builder.setContentTitle("BasicNotification");
       builder.setContentText("Test");
       builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1);

       Notification notification = builder.build();
       NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       manager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);

    }

 private void Notification2() {

       NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
       builder.setAutoCancel(true);
       builder.setContentTitle("BasicNotification");
       builder.setContentText("Test");
       builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);

       Notification notification = builder.build();
       NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
       manager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);

    }

}
```

Thanks up front!

Comment: show me where you define the buttons please

Comment: where did you define the onclick events?? Show the entire code.

Comment: that is the entire code.. i dont have more.. but it worked with normal buttoms

Comment: you need to show us the onCreate() method - @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: i edited it again. is it that what you you want to see? now i have put in the complet code i have nothing more :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your `ImageButtons`

```
 android:onClick="sendNotification"
```

Comment: hey just another question. How do i make, when i click the buttom 2 times, that the first notification goes away and only the newest one stays? Now it is like if i press buttom1 3 times, icon1 is 3times in the status bar? Do you know a simple code?

Comment: @DudeEffects sorry, you should ask a new question

Answer (score -1):

Did you change

```
Button yourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

to

```
ImageButton yourButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

Also, if you show us some code we will be able to assist you more in your query.

Comment: i never used such a line in my code :s
where do i have to put it?

Comment: can you paste your onCreate() method as well? It should be there